# regex for logback log parsing

Tags: regex, logparser

Why isn't the following

```
([a-fA-F0-9]{8}-[a-fA-F0-9]{4}-[a-fA-F0-9]{4}-[a-fA-F0-9]{4}-[a-fA-F0-9]{12}) (\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}) (\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2},\d{3}) \[(.*?)\] ([^ ]*) +([^ ]*) - (.*)$
```

not matching any thing from the following

```
22bd49ad-eff4-4d20-b87d-eae1d0ab90e6 2015-12-28 13:28:19,025 [http-nio-8090-exec-3] DEBUG o.s.b.a.e.mvc.EndpointHandlerMapping apps : Did not find handler method for [/facets/apps/search]
```

EDIT: posting the correct link

Test linK https://regex101.com/r/lV4wU2/1

Comment: Which part of input from this question should `([^ ]*) - (.*)$` match?

Comment: @Tushar added the wrong link earlier. updated it now

Comment: Why do you think your regex should match that piece of text?

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis i got that from another SO post and added my UUID regex to it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this regex:

```
^[a-fA-F0-9]{8}(?:-[a-fA-F0-9]{4}){4}[a-fA-F0-9]{8} (\d{4}(?:-\d{2}){2}) ((?:\d{2}:){2}\d{2},\d{3}) \[(.*?)\] (\S*) +(\S*) [^:]*: (.*?)(?=\n[a-fA-F0-9]{8}|\z)
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/lV4wU2/8)

`[^ ]*` can be replaced by `\S*` in your regex and last part doesn't have hyphen.

Comment: perfect. is it also possible to match the exception stacktraces like below https://regex101.com/r/lV4wU2/4

Comment: Can be **shortened**: `-[a-fA-F0-9]{4}-[a-fA-F0-9]{4}-[a-fA-F0-9]{4}-[a-fA-F0-9]{12}` **==>** `(?:-[a-fA-F0-9]{4}){4}[a-fA-F0-9]{8}` [**Demo**](https://regex101.com/r/lV4wU2/6)

Comment: [ok try this regexc to capture multiline exception trace](https://regex101.com/r/lV4wU2/5)

Comment: Or `^[a-fA-F0-9]{8}(?:-[a-fA-F0-9]{4}){4}[a-fA-F0-9]{8} (\d{4}(?:-\d{2})) (\d{2}(?::\d{2}){2},\d{3}) \[(.*?)\] (\S*) +(\S*) (.*)$`

Comment: Yes Tushar, thanks for the tip. I have included that in recent edit.

Comment: Thanks it is reduced further.

Comment: is there a way to make this work in java/scala? seems like there are difference

Comment: This should work fine in Java. Just use **`String regex = "(?ms)^[a-fA-F0-9]{8}(?:-[a-fA-F0-9]{4}){4}[a-fA-F0-9]{8} (\\d{4}(?:-\\d{2}){2}) ((?:\\d{2}:){2}\\d{2},\\d{3}) \\[(.*?)\\] (\\S*) +(\\S*) [^:]*: (.*?)(?=\n[a-fA-F0-9]{8}|\\z)"`**

Answer (score 1):

The ending part `+([^ ]*) - (.*)` 
doesn't match with

`o.s.b.a.e.mvc.EndpointHandlerMapping apps : Did not find handler method for [/facets/apps/search]`

so the entire expression doesn't match.

**EDIT**
You should try something like that to match your input :
`[a-fA-F0-9]{8}-[a-fA-F0-9]{4}-[a-fA-F0-9]{4}-[a-fA-F0-9]{4}-[a-fA-F0-9]{12} (\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}) (\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2},\d{3}) \[(.*?)\] ([^ ]*) ([^ ]*) (.*)$`

Comment: do you have a suggestion to fix that?

Comment: @prim close. I want everything after o.s.b.a.e.mvc.EndpointHandlerMapping to be treated as one

Comment: @Pangea It is the case, all after is treated as one